# Dealing with pointers causing a segmentation fault in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

Here is the function in question:

```
#include        <cstdlib>
#include    <string>
#include    <iostream>
#include        <unistd.h>
#include        <pthread.h>
#include        "Train.h"
#include        "Platform.h"

const int   NUM_TRAINS      = 4; 
const int   NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS   = NUM_TRAINS / 2;
const int   NUM_SOUTHERNLY_TRAINS   = NUM_TRAINS - NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS;
const int       NUM_LOOPS       = 16;
const char* TRAIN_NAME_ARRAY[NUM_TRAINS]
                = { "Thomas the Tank-Engine",
                    "Percy the Small Engine",
                    "California Zephyr",
                    "Tokaido Shinkansen"
                  };
const int   TRAIN_TRANSIT_TIME_MSECS[NUM_TRAINS]
                = { 10000,  // Thomas
                    10000,  // Percy
                     5000,  // CA Zephyr
                     1000   // Bullet train
                   };

Platform    northBoundPlatform("North-bound Platform");
Platform    southBoundPlatform("South-bound Platform");

void*   initiallyNorthernly (void* vPtr)
{
  Train* id = ((Train*)vPtr);
  for  (int i = 0;  i < NUM_LOOPS;  i++)
  {
    northBoundPlatform.arrive(id);
    northBoundPlatform.leave();
    pause();
    southBoundPlatform.arrive(id);
    southBoundPlatform.leave();
    pause();
  }
  return((void*)id);
}


void*   initiallySouthernly (void* vPtr)
{
  Train* id = (Train*)vPtr;     
  for  (int i = 0;  i < NUM_LOOPS;  i++)
  {
    southBoundPlatform.arrive(id);
    southBoundPlatform.leave();
    pause();
    northBoundPlatform.arrive(id);
    northBoundPlatform.leave();
    pause();
  }
  return((void*)id);

}   


int     main    ()
{
  pthread_t     tidArray[NUM_TRAINS];
  Train*    trainArray[NUM_TRAINS];
  pthread_t     tidArray2[NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS];
  Train*        trainArray2[NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS];
  pthread_t     tidArray3[NUM_SOUTHERNLY_TRAINS];
  Train*        trainArray3[NUM_SOUTHERNLY_TRAINS];

  for  (int i = 0;  i < NUM_TRAINS;  i++)
   { trainArray[i] = new    Train(TRAIN_NAME_ARRAY[i],TRAIN_TRANSIT_TIME_MSECS[i]);
   }
    int trainInd      = 0;


  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS; i++)
  { 
    pthread_create(&tidArray2[i], NULL, initiallyNorthernly,&trainArray2[i]);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SOUTHERNLY_TRAINS; i++)
  {
     pthread_create(&tidArray3[i], NULL, initiallySouthernly,&trainArray3[i]);
  }

  for  (int i = 0;  i < NUM_TRAINS;  i++) 
  {     
     trainArray[i] = NULL;

  //  Wait for all Train threads.  Also, get the pointers to the Train objects
  //  and delete() them because they were created by 'new'
     pthread_join(tidArray[i], (void**)&trainInd);
     pthread_join(tidArray2[i],(void**)&trainInd);
     pthread_join(tidArray3[i],(void**)&trainInd);
  }
  return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Here are the appropriate header files:

Train.h

```
class   Train
{

  std::string   name_;


  int       pauseTimeUsecs_;

public :

  Train     (const std::string& newName,
         int            newPauseTimeUsecs
        )
  {
    name_       = newName;
    pauseTimeUsecs_ = newPauseTimeUsecs;
    std::cout << getName() << " leaving the trainyard.\n";
  }


  ~Train    ()
  {
    std::cout << getName() << " going back to the trainyard\n";
  }

  const std::string&
        getName ()
            const
  { return(name_); }


  void      pause   ()
            const
  {
    usleep(pauseTimeUsecs_);
  }

};
```

Platform.h

```
class   Platform
{

  std::string       name_;


  Train*        trainPtr_;

  pthread_mutex_t  mutexLock_;
  pthread_cond_t    notEmptyCond_;
  pthread_cond_t    notFullCond_;
public :

  Platform      (const std::string& newName
        )
  {
    name_   = newName;
    trainPtr_   = NULL;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutexLock_,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&notEmptyCond_,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&notFullCond_,NULL);
  }

  //  PURPOSE:  To release resources.  No parameters.  No return value.
  ~Platform     ()
  {
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutexLock_);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&notEmptyCond_);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&notFullCond_);
  }


  const std::string&
        getName ()
            const
  {
    return(name_);
  }


  Train*    getTrainPtr
            ()
            const
  {
    return(trainPtr_);
  }


  void      arrive  (Train* newTrainPtr
            )
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock_);
    while  (getTrainPtr() != NULL)
    {
      std::cout << getTrainPtr()->getName()
        << " is at " << getName()
        << ", "      << newTrainPtr->getName()
        << " must wait.\n";
      usleep(10) + rand() % 10;
      pthread_cond_wait(&notFullCond_,&mutexLock_);
    }

    std::cout << newTrainPtr->getName() << " arriving at " << getName()     << "\n";

    trainPtr_   = newTrainPtr;

    usleep(10 + rand() % 10);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock_);
    pthread_cond_signal(&notEmptyCond_);
  }


  Train*    leave   ()
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexLock_);
    while  (getTrainPtr() == NULL)
    {
      std::cout << "No train at " << getName() << "!\n";
      usleep(10 + rand() % 10);
      pthread_cond_wait(&notEmptyCond_,&mutexLock_);
    }

    Train*  toReturn    = getTrainPtr();

    std::cout << toReturn->getName() << " leaving " << getName() << "\n";

    usleep(10 + rand() % 10);
    trainPtr_ = NULL;
    pthread_cond_signal(&notFullCond_);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexLock_);
    return(toReturn);
  }

};
```

After running with gdb, the segmentation fault is occurring when I call arrive on northBoundPlatform(a Platform object). The goal of the function is to make the train object that is pointed to by vPtr arrive() at northernPlatform, leave() at northernPlatform, pause() on the train object, arrive() at the southBoundPlatform, leave() the southBoundPlatform, pause() on the object again, and finally return a pointer to the train that was used.

I am not sure if I am casting vPtr into a Train* correctly which is causing a segmentation fault. I can provide the rest of the main code if necessary. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the procedure launching the thread in-question intentionally left to the imagination, and as such, likewise the lifetime of the `Train` object being passed by address? *How do you set up the thread , the parameter passed to it, and the lifetime of both* ? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be highly preferable.

Comment: I don't see anything that verifies that the passed in pointer is actually valid before you act on it.  Then, in `arrive`, you do check to see if it's null but then do things with it outside of that check.

Comment: Unrelated, `usleep(10) + rand() % 10;` always sleeps for 10 microseconds then calculates some random value modulo 10, adds that to the result returned from `usleep`, and does nothing with the final result. Pretty sure you meant `usleep(10 + (rand) % 10);`

Comment: You sure your vPtr pointer of function initiallyNorthernly carrying a valid pointer value?

Comment: Ok, I added the rest of the code to maybe make more sense. Did I possibly create my threads wrong? I am basically creating threads that run the functions initiallyNorthernly() and initiallySouthernly(). Each thread is getting a pointer to its own train instance, which is an array of pointers to trains, not the trains themselves.

Comment: @SciGuy: This code doesn't even compile: https://gist.github.com/sharth/5a0df169b28723d33894

Comment: Sorry, I posted an older version. The updated version as is will compile, but I know that it still causes a seg fault.

Comment: Check your array usage in `main()`. the same array elements, `&tidArray[i]`, are being used for both sets of launch-loops. The second overwrites the first. That in itself is a significant problem, as you'll orphan the thread handles for the first batch, and wait on indeterminate thread handles in your final join-loop. You're also passing `&i` as the thread data, the lifetime of which is only local to each loop. An dangling `int*` is not a valid `Train*`, so yeah, you could say a number of things are setup wrong.

Comment: So say I created some new pthreads and new Train* arrays, something like   pthread_t   tidArray2[NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS] and                                  Train*         trainArray2[NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS].  Then I use those to create the threads for initiallyNorthernly. Am I on the right track with this?

Comment: Voted to close because tbh it's unclear what you're asking, you don't seem to be very clear on what you're asking, and this reads like a homework question.

Answer (score 1):

Your main() function has two for loops for each of NUM_NORTHERNLY_TRAINS, using initiallyNorthernly and initiallySouthernly, but the second loop should be looping with NUM_SOUTHERNLY_TRAINS instead.

Comment: Thank you, I noticed that while trying some new stuff out. I have updated my code and after running it still throws a seg fault. After debugging again the problem still seems to be in the function initiallyNorthernly(), specifically when passing it the id variable I created. I must be doing something wrong with the casting, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Like an infomercial, "But wait!  There's more!"    trainArray2[i] is a Train*, and you're passing the address of a Train*.  It looks like you should remove the &, and then initiallyNorthernly() will receive the expected type.